# Remove part of string coming from database

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, junit, assert

This **usuario.get(3)** get from database the string **"202019"** but on the screen I get only **19**.

```
Assert.assertEquals(usuario.get(3), pedidoPage.obterCicloConsultora(driver));
```

I want remove **"2020"** to make my assertion works.

Please, help me !!! Thank you !!!

Comment: You should check the String functions `replace()` and `substring()`

Comment: print both `usuario.get(3)`and `pedidoPage.obterCicloConsultora(driver)` to see which values you obtain in each. probably your frontend gets that date and just removes 2020.. why can't you do the same? you can just do something like `usuario.get(3).substring(4)` et voilá

Comment: i think you are doing it wrong , point of assertion is to check the output with a static value , why you want to use usuario.get(3) instead of "2020" , and if you want to test using usuario.get(3) this , and if it fails that means it really failed , identify why usuario.get(3) this one returns you 202019 ,

Comment: Thnaks guys. My problem was solved !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

Assert.assertEquals(usuario.get(3).substring(4), pedidoPage.obterCicloConsultora(driver));

Answer (score 0):

If the method usuario.get(int) returns a String, you can try:

```
usuario.get(3).replace("2020","")
```

Regards